# How to get sat and sun dates from given date ranges in python

Tags: python

How to get saturday and sunday dates from given date range.

for example :

```
  start_date = 2011-09-01
  end_date = 2011-09-15
```

Now it should give the out put

```
2011-09-03
2011-09-04
2011-09-10
2011-09-11
```

Any help really appreciate.

Comment: Have you done any research for yourself? There are *tons* of Python date manipulation tutorials on the web.

Comment: yes doing, once i get something will update this thread

Comment: Well then, sir, I'd ask this question *after* you can't find anything from your research ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
  for n in range((end_date - start_date).days):
    yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = '2011-09-01'
end_date = '2011-09-15'
format = '%Y-%m-%d'

start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, format)
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, format)

for day in daterange(start_date_object, end_date_object):
  if day.weekday() in [5, 6]:
    print day.strftime(format)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-09-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> while start <= end:
...     if start.weekday() in (5, 6):
...         print start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
...     start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
...
2011-09-03
2011-09-04
2011-09-10
2011-09-11
>>>
```